# PiCamera Video Corruption

Tags: python, picamera

I'm trying to save video from my picam and it ends up like this:[image]

```
import picamera

# set up camera
camera = picamera.PiCamera();
camera.resolution = (640, 480);
camera.framerate = 24;

# record
camera.start_preview();
camera.start_recording("basic.h264");
camera.wait_recording(10);
camera.stop_recording();
camera.stop_preview();
print("Finished Recording");
```

The vertical bands are 128px wide. This holds true under every camera resolution I tried. The green corruption looks the same in every video I saved that had the same resolution.

I tried rebooting the pi and unplugging and replugging the camera ribbon. The camera feed looks fine in preview or when I view the camera stream with opencv. Raspistill also works fine. It's only a problem when I save the video and try to reopen it.

I'm using PiCamera 1.3 with Python 3.7 running on a Pi 4

Update: I got a new pi camera (v2) and the corruption is still there

Update2: I've replaced the camera module, the sd card, and even got a new Pi 4 and the problem is still there. It also shows up using raspivid (tested with this command):

raspivid -t 30000 -w 640 -h 480 -fps 25 -b 1200000 -p 0,0,640,480 -o pivideo.h264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like my Raspbian Buster image was corrupted or something.I kept refreshing my sd cards from the raspbian buster image that I had downloaded from the official raspberry site. This time I downloaded a new RB image from the site and the problem went away.